# Нельзя удалить контакт

Tags: java, android-sdk, android

Программно добавляю контакт, но потом когда хочу его удалить не получается. Пишет "Невозможно удалить контакты из аккаунта, доступного только для чтения, однако их можно скрыть в списках контактов."
Добавлять так.

```
private void addContact(String name) {
    Utils utils = Utils.getInstance(this);
    if (utils.contactExists(name)) return;
    Account account = utils.getAccount(ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
    int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account != null ? account.type : null)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account != null ? account.name : null)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, "Semen")
            .withValue(CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, "Middle name")
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
            .withValue(Data.DATA1, 12345)
            .withValue(Data.DATA2, "sample")
            .withValue(Data.DATA3, "sample")
            .build());
    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] results = getContentResolver().applyBatch(AUTHORITY, ops);
        for (ContentProviderResult result : results) {
            Log.d("logba", "addContact : result=" + result);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

syncadapter.xml

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.example.account"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="true"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
    android:supportsUploading="true"
    android:userVisible="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Привет, попробуй так.

```
public boolean deleteContact(Activity activity, String id) {
        try {
            final ArrayList ops = new ArrayList();
            final ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI).withSelection(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                    + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}).build());
            cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            ops.clear();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```